# CSS transition not working with ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, css

I'm relatively new to doing animations with CSS, having some experience with JQuery in the past, but I noticed that the animation was really choppy on smaller devices like my iPad, nook and android phone. I decided to instead use a CSS transition instead by toggling a class with jquery.

When the ajax content is loaded a class of `hidden` is applied to the `<section>` tag that contains the portion of the page I want to load. I have a page with full markup in case the user doesn't have javascript enabled, but when they do I want to grab the `<section id="sectionId">` - `sectionId` changes from page to page, ie `<section id="home">` for index.html, `<section id="contact">` for contact.html, and `<section id="products">` for products.html,  but for the sake of keeping the example generic, I'll use `sectionId`.

So how it should function is like this:

1. Replace the content in `#content` through ajax, grabbing the `#sectionId` from whatever url the navigation link they clicked on points to.
2. Add the `hidden` class after it's loaded.
3. Remove the `hidden` class so the CSS transition fires and the loaded section slides in from the right.

Here's the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <section id="sectionId">
        <!-- Content In Here -->
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content > section
{
    margin-left: 0;
    -moz-transition: .5s all ease-in;
    -o-transition: .5s all ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-in;
    transition: .5s all ease-in;
}

#content > section.hidden
{
    margin-left: 2000px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
function loadPage(container, url, sectionId) {

    container.load(url + ' #' + sectionId);
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    $('#content > section').addClass('hidden');        
    $('#content > section').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

This works for the index page and #home section only. However, I commented out the JQuery that removes the `hidden` class and confirmed in the developer tools that the class is initially being added to each of the loaded sections, however, the transition only seems to happen to the index page. On the other pages the sections are loaded and the `hidden` class is also removed as intended, but the sliding transition does not happen. You can leave the home page, all the other pages load without transitions, when you go back to the home page, the transition happens as intended. You never navigated away from index.html no matter what link is clicked on, I basically have the site reloading the home page content through ajax too.

If there's a better way to do this with css I'm all ears. Additionally, I'm having trouble with how the `hidden` class is added in the first place. Depending on the browser it's loaded in and the internet connection speed sometimes the content is displayed for a moment before the class is added and the new margin is rendered.

Comment: I will read fully in a minute, though it seems that you're having a problem because the HTML element is not present on the page loads (when the CSS loads).  If you have an initial element in there with the class name when the pages loads (before AJAX) then it will load properly, or you will have to apply the CSS to the AJAX elements after it posts - including the transition

Comment: I second this. Add a transition class to the content that is added to the section after it has already been added and it should "ease-in"

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a little? I don't seem to understand what you mean by adding a transition class.

Comment: Gary, one way I would do something like this is to already have the elements that you need to transition in on the page.  For instance, your containers can all be available when you load the page, then do the AJAX call and push information into them, then they can use your CSS transition class at any time

Comment: Alright, I will play around with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should be

```
function loadPage(container, url, sectionId) {
    $('#content > section').addClass('hidden');        
    container.load(url + ' #' + sectionId);
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    $('#content > section').removeClass('hidden');
});
```